# Nonlinear mappings between finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

When one studies Linear Algebra, I think it is natural to wonder what happens if we retain the linear structure of the vector spaces (addition and scalar multiplication) and let the mappings between them become more general than the linear mappings, like the ones studied in calculus, now in many variables: polynomials, trigonometric, logarithmic, exponential, etc.

So, which branch of mathematics studies nonlinear mappings between finite dimensional vector spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Calculus is a good start. And to study those mappings, we often approximate them locally with linear mappings, about which there are lots more theorems.